# How can I store and update totals each time I run the program

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that calculates gas expense.

The user inputs:

- The price of gas
- How many gallons the car can hold
- How much gas is currently going into the tank (estimate of either 0, .25, .5 , .75).

Calculations are done and what's then displayed is:

- Current Total (price of gas this fill up)
- Monthly total (assumed that user fills up gas 2.5 times a month)
- Annual total (monthly * 12)

What I now look to do is create a prompt that asks "Create a new car?" or "Use current car":

- If it's create a new car, totals start at 0.
- If it's use current car, totals should be pulled from a stored location.

I'm looking for a way for the input to be stored in a database (or would a file work better?) so that it can keep track of the totals each time I start the program, and close it.

For example, if I fill up gas and my current total is $32.54, I want monthly and annual totals to change from 0.00 to $32.54. Then next time opening it, monthly and annual should show $32.54 until I add another current total.

My current code when a button called "calculate" is clicked:

```
// Variables
double gasPrice;
double gasInTank;      // How much gas is in the tank
double lessGas = 0.0;  // Essentially, what needs to be filled up.
double currentTotal;
double monthlyExpense;
double annualExpense;
double maxGallons;

gasPrice = double.Parse(txtGasPrice.Text);
maxGallons = double.Parse(txtMaxGas.Text);
gasInTank = double.Parse(txtGasInTank.Text);

if (gasInTank == 0)
{
    lessGas = maxGallons;
}
else if (gasInTank == .25)
{
    lessGas = maxGallons * .75;
}
else if (gasInTank == .5)
{
    lessGas = maxGallons / 2;
}
else if (gasInTank == .75)
{
    lessGas = maxGallons * .25;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Accepted values are : '0', '.25', '.5', and '.75'");
}

currentTotal = gasPrice * lessGas;
monthlyExpense = currentTotal * 2.5;
annualExpense = monthlyExpense * 12;
lblCurrentShow.Text = currentTotal.ToString("c");
lblMonthShow.Text = monthlyExpense.ToString("c");
lblAnnualShow.Text = annualExpense.ToString("c");
```

I'm sorry if this is hard to understand, or to0 "noob" of a question, but it has been at least a year since I've done anything in C# and I am trying to refresh my way of thinking before I start my first job right out of college as a programmer.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is wrap up your locals into a type, serialize it, then write that data to a file on the disk. When the program loads look for that file and de-serialize the contents back into an instance of the type and continue like normal.

Comment: Unrelated, but what't the purpose of `maxGallons - 0`?

Comment: @Brian, I guess it would make more sense if it was just = maxGallons.

Comment: @asawyer, I would have to look into that because I haven't learned how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on several factors, the most important of which is how many users are going to use this application and how often. Also, where the application runs is important, is this a desktop or a web.
Having said that, I will assume it's a desktop and for 1 user.

Several options to store the information:

1. Store the values in a local XML file - use `XmlSerializer` 
   ([XmlSerializer of Simple Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)   [XmlSerializer example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))
2. Store the values in a sqlite database - use the `System.Data.SQLite`
   (ADO.NET adapter for SQLite)
   ([SQLite example](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/))
3. Cache the values - `OutputCacheProvider` 
   ( System.Runtime.Caching.dll contains chaching API for non-web apps)
   ([OutputCacheProvider example](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1423/filebased-cache-for-web-and-nonweb-apps-plus--extend-aspnet-40-outputcacheprovider.aspx))

Comment: Right now, its designed for just 1 user. It is also a Windows Form so its for my desktop. I will read over your options and look into them.

Comment: if you're a beginner I would suggest to use the serialization, it's the easiest and would be a valuable exercise.

Comment: Does the example of "Serializing a Class that Contains a Field Returning a Complex Object" the one that pertains to my question? or Serializing an XmlElement and XmlNode?

Comment: there is 'purchase order example' below in the link, look at it to get the idea of how you apply serialization.

Comment: added Simple Object example

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to promote the values you want to persist to fields or properties

In this case I think just `currentTotal` so,

```
public class yourClass
{
    public double CurrentTotal {get;set;}

    protected void yourButtonClickCode()
    {
        // use the proeprty ref here instead of the local
    }

}
```

Now on exit you want to save the value of that to a local file:

```
public class yourClass
{
    public double CurrentTotal {get;set;}

    protected void yourButtonClickCode()
    {
        // use the proeprty ref here instead of the local
    }

    protected void onExit() 
    {
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"your path.txt", this.CurrentTotal.ToString());
    }    

}
```

Now that we are saving the data, we can write code to load it up as well:

```
public class yourClass
{
    public double CurrentTotal {get;set;}

    protected void yourButtonClickCode()
    {
        // use the proeprty ref here instead of the local
    }

    public yourClass()
    {
       if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"your file.txt"))
       {
           this.CurrentTotal = double.Parse( System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"your file.txt"));
       }
       else
       {
           this.CurrentTotal = 0d;
       }
    }

    protected void onExit()
    {
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"your path.txt", this.CurrentTotal.ToString());
    }    

}
```

How to get the `onExit` event working depends on what type of project this is (wpf/winforms/console ect)

This doesn't work with multiple cars ect, I'll leave you to work out those details, but this is the general idea.

If it was a database instead, you'd replace those IO calls with database calls.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to reread this, and try it out. It gets the ball rolling.  The type of project is a Windows Form

Comment: parsing a file like that is really a pain, if he is going to modify/add parts to his program etc, not a good style.

Comment: at least add some memory management like 'using' and a try-catch